# How to prevent Java code from not executing?

Tags: java

I'm still fairly new to Java and was wondering if anyone could tell me why the terminal won't output anything when running the program below -

The program compiles and can be executed with java ArraysTwoD, but it just stalls after that...

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArraysTwoD
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declaring variables
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int result = 0;

        // two dimensional array
        int [][] twoDArray;
        twoDArray = new int[row][col];

        // initialising scanner method
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // gaining inputs from user
        row = sc.nextInt();
        col = sc.nextInt();

        // calculating the product of each element
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                result = twoDArray[i][j] * twoDArray[i][j];

                twoDArray[i][j] = result;
            }
        }

        //outputting each element to the user in matrix fashion
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(twoDArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        // closing scanner method
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Your program is waiting for user input, 2 integers specifically. The problem is: you don't tell the user what to do so that's a classic human-machine deadlock: the machine is waiting for the human and the human is waiting for the machine :)

Comment: The title of this question makes my head hurt

Comment: general advice. This code so much outdated. If you are new to java, start with Java 9 + standards

Comment: @OlafKock this is one of those questions where 'Why is this Java code not executing?' would actually be an improvement. LOL

Answer (score 1):

You're initialing your twoDArray like this :  `twoDArray = new int[0][0];`  before getting the user input. Move it like I did.
Also this line `result = twoDArray[i][j] * twoDArray[i][j];` will give error because your twoDArray is empty, you have to fill it.
If you want to fill with int from 1 to `row*col` do like I did.
And your program is waiting for user input, so it is also important to let the user know what to do, add a sop to tell him what to do.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArraysTwoD
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declaring variables
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int result = 0;

        // two dimensional array
        int [][] twoDArray;
        

        // initialising scanner method
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // gaining inputs from user
       System.out.println("Enter the number of rows");
        row = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of column");
        col = sc.nextInt();
       
        twoDArray = new int[row][col];

        // calculating the product of each element
        for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= col; j++)
            {
                

                twoDArray[i][j] = i*j;
            }
        }

        //outputting each element to the user in matrix fashion
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(twoDArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        // closing scanner method
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the big  issue here is: to add a simple print statement before the calls to nextInt() so that the user understands why the program  is "stalling".

Comment: This is a good point, I will modify my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it stall because scanner is waiting for your input?

I think you should also move your two dimensional array declaration after the reading of the input like this:

```
    // initialising scanner method
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // gaining inputs from user
    row = sc.nextInt();
    col = sc.nextInt();

    // two dimensional array
    int [][] twoDArray;
    twoDArray = new int[row][col];
```